# Error in breeze using EF 5 and calling stored procedure

Tags: breeze

Getting an error client side with breeze: "Cannot call method 'map' of undefined" when trying to pull over some data. The difference between this action and one that works is that this action is calling a stored procedure and returning `ObjectResult<T>` instead of `DbSet<T>`.

Might this be why I get an error? Using Chrome Developer tools, I do see that the breeze controller is returning json data.

I have created a complex model type in the edmx for mapping the rows returned from the stored procedure.

The action in the breeze controller has a return type of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error when using an EF complex type.  A workaround was to create a view in my database instead of using a complex type, set the stored procedure to return a type of the new view which had a primary key and then it worked.  It would seem that breeze requires entities to have a primary key defined.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... not quite sure what is happening, so just guessing here, but try adding an AsQueryable() to the result returned, and changing the result type to a IQueryable.

We don't have any stored proc tests for breeze yet, but this is impetus for me to add some :)

Comment: Tried AsQueryable() but didn't fix the problem. The json data is coming over fine. Assuming the problem is mapping the data with the metadata? Would there be an issue if the edmx is part of a different namespace/project?

Comment: Does this help: breeze.debug.js line 3818 entityType.keyProperties.map(...), keyProperties is undefined. rawEntity has good data in it, entityType looks good too.

Comment: Yes, that helps.  Breeze needs a key property or properties defined for every entityType.  This is necessary in order for the entityManager to be able to merge entities.  My guess is that the Edmx for this entityType does not have a key defined.  I haven't looked at EF stored procs for awhile but I seem to recall some way to tell EF what columns of the result constitutes a key.  If not, let me know and we will come up with another idea.  I'll also insure that we throw a more meaningful error message in future for this condition.

Comment: This is really "lookup" data, so I projected the data to an anonymous type and push'd the data into a ko.observablearray. Works for now :)

Comment: Now I have an sp that returns an object that does include a key. Any idea how to tell breeze that column is the key? Or how could I remove the metadata for that object from breeze so it doesn't try and map it? Don't want to keep creating anonymous types like I did for the previous sp.

Comment: If you are creating the metadata for the type on the client, each  dataProperty has an 'isPartOfKey' property .  See http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/DataProperty.html

Comment: The metadata is coming server side (EF5) with a call to api\..\metadata. Can I change it client side to include isPartOfKey after it's downloaded?

Comment: Did some research, the metatype for the objects coming from the stored procedure are in the "complexTypes" array and there is no column marked as key even though i used data annotations to mark one as [key]. Therefore, I get an error when I try and query this data because there is no key column. Any idea when this will get worked on? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue, but thank God I figured out a solution. Instead of using a stored procedure, you should use a view, as Breeze recognizes views as `DbSet<T>`, just like tables. Say you have a SQL server table that contains two tables Customers and Orders.

```
Customers (**CustomerId**, FirstName, LastName)
Orders (OrderId, #CustomerId, OrderDate, OrderTotal)
```

Now, say you want a query that returns orders by CustomerId. Usually, you would do that in a stored procedure, but as I said, you need to use a view instead. So the query will look like this in the view.

```
Select o.OrderId, c.CustomerId, o.OrderDate, o.OrderTotal
from dbo.Orders o inner join dbo.Customers c on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId
```

Notice there is no filtering (where ...). So:

i. Create a [general] view that includes the filtering key(s) and name it, say, `OrdersByCustomers`

ii. Add the OrdersByCustomers view to the entity model in your VS project

iii. Add the entity to the Breeze controller, as such:

```
public IQueryable<OrdersByCustomers> OrdersByCustomerId(int id)  
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.OrdersByCustomers
                                   .Where(r => r.CustomerId == id);
}
```

Notice the **.Where(r => r.CustomerId == id)** filter. We could do it in the data service file, but because we want the user to see only his personal data, we need to filter from the server so it only returns his data.

iv. Now, that the entity is set in the controller, you may invoke it in the data service file, as such:

```
var getOrdersByCustomerId = function(orderObservable, id)
{
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('OrdersByCustomerId')
                                  .WithParameters({ CustomerId: id });

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
                  .then(function(data) {
                      if (orderObservable) orderObservable(data.results);
                  }
                  .fail(function(e) {
                      logError('Retrieve Data Failed');
                  }
}
```

v. You probably know what to do next from here.

Hope it helps.